# Bash Shell Curl JSON variable pass

Tags: json, shell, curl

I was trying to do CURL call from shell script and command line argument.

```
url=$1
pg=$2
coockie=$3

curl '$url' -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' -H 'origin: $url' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36' -H 'content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'referer: $url' -H 'authority: recruiting.adp.com' -H '$cookie' -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' --data-binary $'{"filters":[{"name":"country","label":"Country"},{"name":"state","label":"State"},{"name":"grp","label":"Job Type"},{"name":"ptitle","label":"Job"}],"results":{"pageTitle":"Search Results","zeroResultsMessage":"We\'re sorry but we have no job openings at this time that match your search criteria. Please try another search.","searchFailureMessage":"Oops\u0021 Something went wrong.  Search has encountered a problem. Try searching again","resultsFoundLabel":"results found","bookmarkText":"Bookmark This","pageSize":"100","sortOrder":"00001000","shareText":"Share","fields":[{"name":"ptitle","label":"Published Job Title"},{"name":"location","label":"Location"},{"name":"position","label":"Position"}]},"pagefilter":{"page": 3},"rl":"enUS"}' --compressed
```

echo "$url $pg"

But "pagefilter":{"page": 3},"rl":"enUS"}' in this page attribute script is working when it's a numeric value but i want to have it like "pagefilter":{"page": "$page"},"rl":"enUS"}'

Unable to understand why it's not working. Tried escaping double quotation too.

Input is like /s.sh "URL" 3 1234

Comment: hi, could you put the relevant parts of your curl call into your post?

Comment: I have added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jschnnasse
Tried with bash -x and found out that only '$pg' taking the value
"pg" , "'$pg'" and '"$pg"' not working 
following code is working perfectly.

```
url=$1
pg=$2
coockie=$3

curl '$url' -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' -H 'origin: $url' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36' -H 'content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'referer: $url' -H 'authority: recruiting.adp.com' -H '$cookie' -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' --data-binary $'{"filters":[{"name":"country","label":"Country"},{"name":"state","label":"State"},{"name":"grp","label":"Job Type"},{"name":"ptitle","label":"Job"}],"results":{"pageTitle":"Search Results","zeroResultsMessage":"We\'re sorry but we have no job openings at this time that match your search criteria. Please try another search.","searchFailureMessage":"Oops\u0021 Something went wrong.  Search has encountered a problem. Try searching again","resultsFoundLabel":"results found","bookmarkText":"Bookmark This","pageSize":"100","sortOrder":"00001000","shareText":"Share","fields":[{"name":"ptitle","label":"Published Job Title"},{"name":"location","label":"Location"},{"name":"position","label":"Position"}]},"pagefilter":{"page": '$pg'},"rl":"enUS"}' --compressed
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your variable with double/single/double quotes `"'"` will help in [most cases](https://superuser.com/questions/835587/how-to-include-environment-variable-in-bash-line-curl)

```
page=3
curl -d'{"page":"'"$page"'"}' http://...
```

This will be expanded to

```
curl -d'{"page":"3"}' http://...
```

Or use only single/double qoutes`'"` to expand to a number:

```
curl -d'{"page":'"$page"'}' http://...
```

Will be expandend to

```
curl '-d{"page":3}'
```

Comment: Maybe try the 2nd with `'"` only.  If this doesn't help we are on the wrong track.

Comment: Tried all but not working. It's working only when am sending static numbers.

Comment: You are passing the wrong variable then. Execute your script with `bash -x` to inspect what is happening.

Comment: Ok checking that one.

Comment: Thanks. Found the solution posted.